# XCode jumps out to assembler spontaneously

Tags: ios, xcode, assembly, opengl-es

XCode jumps me out to assembler after 1-2 minutes of working in iOS simulator. (I have XCode 4.6.2 )

- This is not an exception (I have global breakpoint for that)
- This is not Assert or `BAD ACCESS` - I can press play button on the bottom of the screen and application moves forward.

Usually it breaks somewhere on:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4); (I am using OpenGL 1.1)
```

This happens almost every time with 90% replicability
Why does it jump out to assembler? Do I have any issue in application?

Usually it break here

```
OpenGLES`glDrawArrays:
0xcc50dd:  pushl  %ebp
0xcc50de:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0xcc50e0:  pushl  %edi
0xcc50e1:  pushl  %esi
0xcc50e2:  subl   $16, %esp
0xcc50e5:  movl   $30, (%esp)
0xcc50ec:  calll  0xccb5c2                  ; symbol stub for: pthread_getspecific
0xcc50f1:  testl  %eax, %eax
0xcc50f3:  je     0xcc5116                  ; glDrawArrays + 57
0xcc50f5:  movl   16(%ebp), %ecx
0xcc50f8:  movl   12(%ebp), %edx
0xcc50fb:  movl   8(%ebp), %esi
0xcc50fe:  movl   16(%eax), %edi
0xcc5101:  movl   %ecx, 12(%esp)
0xcc5105:  movl   %edx, 8(%esp)
0xcc5109:  movl   %esi, 4(%esp)
0xcc510d:  movl   %edi, (%esp)
0xcc5110:  calll  *280(%eax)
0xcc5116:  addl   $16, %esp   <<<<<< Usually it break here
0xcc5119:  popl   %esi
0xcc511a:  popl   %edi
0xcc511b:  popl   %ebp
0xcc511c:  ret
```

or like this:

```
0x18401c64:  cvttps2dq%xmm4, %xmm0   <<< Thread 1: EXC_??? (11) (code=0, subcode=0x0)
0x18401c68:  movaps %xmm4, %xmm5
0x18401c6b:  psrld  $31, %xmm5
0x18401c70:  psubd  %xmm5, %xmm0
0x18401c74:  movdqa %xmm0, -3592(%ebp)
0x18401c7c:  pshufd $80, 48(%esi), %xmm5
```

stack here:

```
0 0x1880210a
6 glDrawArrays
7 [Displaybrush.....] //my method for display
```

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint set there?

Comment: I am almost sure this question has nothing to do with "assembly" tag.

Comment: No i don't have any breakpoint there. I set also Try Catch with breakpoint for DrawArray but this breakpoint did not fired. I have set global breakpoint for exception but also did not fired.

Comment: It would only "jump out" to a disassembler listing because the app stopped there for some reason.

Comment: I have added code where it breaks (see above). It happens after 3-4 minutes of running application. Do you know why it stops just there? And why I can continue code from that point with no issues? while I press play?

Comment: And you're saying that the button at the bottom of the source listing went from "stop" (`=`) to "play" (`>`) when this happened??

Comment: Check your console listing.

Comment: Console listing is empty (only my data)     Yes, while this happens I see (|>) button at the bottom of source listing, and while I press it application moves further with no issue.

Comment: How did it get to `|>`?  What caused that?  You're saying you don't have any breakpoints set anywhere (except for exceptions)?

Comment: When it jumps out to assembler I see this (|>) exactly like I would press ( || ) button. But of course I didn't. I have few breakpoints in code usually but not on assembler level and not in OpenGL area.  For quite long time I thought that I have just exception - and that is why I have done try-catch on this area and global exceptions breakpoint.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint at the end of a method, the breakpoint may not take effect until after the method returns, in certain odd cases.  Disable all your breakpoints (or try them in halves) and see if the symptom goes away.

Comment: When it stops, go to the stack display and see what is above/below the selected stack fraom.

Comment: Stack added above. (I wanted to add pictures but I need to have reputation minimum 10 to do that) :(

Comment: above in the stack is always glDrawArrays. I have removed all breakpoints, but it didn't help.